# Adding roles using author ID

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Whenever I try to use this command it gives an error, I have tried several methods and it always gives an error, what am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
exports.run = async (database, client, message, args) => {
    const roleadd = await message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Sem Whitelist')

    client.users.fetch(message.author.id).then(user => {
        user.roles.add(roleadd)
    })
    
    message.reply('done.')
}
```

Error Code:

```
(node:2248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

**EDIT**

User Log:

```
User {
  id: '354395231002820608',
  username: 'Pinheiro',
  bot: false,
  discriminator: '2202',
  avatar: 'a_c0697e7f736cb3fac9ef44a33f23ee6a',
  flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 256 },
  lastMessageID: '766703250878627891',
  lastMessageChannelID: '765642688162299905'
}
```

Comment: is user.roles an array? it looks like user.roles is undefined. can you log the user and share the data with us?

Comment: Sure. Topic edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add roles for the user, please use the below code.

```
exports.run = async (database, client, message, args) => {
    const roleadd = await message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Sem Whitelist')

    client.users.fetch(message.author.id).then(user => {
        user.roles = roleadd;
    })
    
    message.reply('done.')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

user does not have a roles object. You will need to get the guildMember.
You can fetch the guildMember object by:

```js
message.guild.member('userID');
```

To add a role to the message author you will use:

```js
exports.run = async (database, client, message, args) => {
    const role = await message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Sem Whitelist')

    let user = message.author;
    user = message.guild.member(user);
    user.roles.add(role).then({
        message.reply('done.')
    });
}
```